# What is the origin of this space station design concept and animation?

Tags: identify-this-object, space-station

In the beginning of the ABC News video [STEM industries are growing, but face shortage of qualified workers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2C1vGWranuI) an illustration of a space station is shown, first with two cross-trusses each with solar panels reminiscent of the ISS' and then with a rotating ring with (presumably) habitat modules around it circling the main structure between the two cross-trusses.

**Question:** What is the origin of this space station design concept and animation? Does anybody recognize this design? Is it some random animation for the ABC News piece or is this file footage associated with a real space station design?

[image: screen shot of conceptual artwork of a space station in the ABC News video STEM industries are growing, but face shortage of qualified workers https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2C1vGWranuI]
[image: screen shot of conceptual artwork of a space station in the ABC News video STEM industries are growing, but face shortage of qualified workers https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2C1vGWranuI]

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, its just stock content, nothing special.

https://www.canstockphoto.com/international-space-station-51622734.html

https://www.canstockphoto.com/international-space-station-51622724.html

They do seem to get around, I saw this design, not the video, maybe a short while back.

Note the title is "International space station orbiting earth" - sometimes a quick search brings up results like these and an agency will just buy it and use it without delving any further.

Comment: yep there it is, [J. J. Abrams-*esque* lens flare and all](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ALHiJaSPrns) :-)

Comment: but.. i like.. lens flares! Used them in everything I did, back in 1993...